# Run a Python script that imports another python script from a different location

Tags: python, pytest, python-import, importerror

I have two python scripts, `x.py` and `test_x.py`, I want to import `x` from
`test_x`.

- `x.py` is located at  `./foo/bar/baz/x.py`
- `test_x.py` is located at  `./tests/test_x.py`

Contents of `x.py`

```py
def f(x):
    return x + 1
```

Contents of `test_x.py`

```py
import foo.bar.baz.x as x

def test_f():
    assert x.f(1) == 2, "Error"
```

I then try running the above as:

```py
pytest -m tests/test_x.py
```

Which gives me the error:

```
tests/test_x.py:1: in <module>
    import foo.bar.baz.x as x
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'
```

So - how should I go about running the above test?

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` in each directory (`foo, bar, and baz`)? You need that for Python to recognize that directory as an importable "module".

Comment: @baxx I recommend taking a look at [relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: @puppydog i'm trying to import scripts though, not directories

Comment: yes, scripts that you've nested in directories. check out @Jay Mody's post

Comment: That’s not how `-m` is supposed to be used: it expects a **module** name.